# Cannot enable USB in Ubuntu 20.04 running on VirtualBox 6.1

Tags: usb, virtualbox, 20.04, users

I want to enable USB Controller in Ubuntu 20.04 running on VirtualBox 6.1

My USB is 3.0 so I installed VirtualBox Extension Pack (all supported platforms) from http://www.virtualbox.org/wiki/Downloads.

I cannot add my Ubuntu host account into group `vboxusers`, so I added it into group `vboxsf` by:

```
sudo usermod -aG vboxusers trinh
usermod: group 'vboxusers' does not exist
sudo usermod -a -G vboxsf "$USER"
```

I rebooted the system and also shutdown my Windows host OS, but it still doesn't recognize the USB drive.

[image]

Comment: Did you install the extension pack on the host or guest system?

Comment: @danzel I installed from Oracle VM VirtualBox Manager. Then I choose `File -> Preferences -> Extensions `

Comment: @danzel I thinks it already installed since as default, the USB setting only configured the USB 1.0 . I think the main issue is that I don't have the `vboxusers` group, which I cannot enable other USB Controller

Comment: So your host is Windows and your guest system is Ubuntu? The OHCI controller (USB 1.1) is available without the extension pack. A lot of settings can only be changed when the guest is not running, so make sure you shutdown Ubuntu before opening the settings dialog. The `vboxsf` group is only relevant for shared folders. The `vboxusers` group is only relevant (and present) on an Ubuntu _host_.

Comment: @danzel Yes you right ! I have shutdown Ubuntu  and change the setting dialog. I can now choose `USB 3.0 (xHCI) controller` and also add my USB name to USB device filter for permanent access in guest . However on bottom panel of the VirtualBox Manager on the USB icon when I right mouse clock and choose the USB to enable it in guest it notify `fail to attach device ... to virtual machine Ubuntu 20.04`

Comment: I haven't tried it yet. Maybe this will work: https://www.linuxbabe.com/virtualbox/access-usb-from-virtualbox-guest-os